# On click...Goto a scene within embedded swf

Tags: flash

Hope the following makes some sense:

I have a 'parent' flash swf that loads up a series of 'child' swfs on respective button releases.  Click 'Button 1' and "button_1.swf" is loaded etc..

Button actions in the child swf are essentially being ignored. For example:

on(release) {
    with (_level0) {
        gotoAndPlay("scene_in_child1");
    }
}

Which works fine in the self-contained child swf (where the button in question is located), hoped it would also work through the parent swf to jump to "scene_in_child1" (in child1.swf).

Clearly something is wrong with my targeting here, where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

aha - solved this, ridiculously simple - used _parent.gotoAndPlay.  Thanks anyway.